# Structured data on different lists view

Tags: schema.org

I have a question about structured data. There are several different lists on my site:

- main sections (categories) and galleries in the main column.
- the most popular and other lists (e.g. calendar) in the right column
- related news (on the single view) below the content

The structure presentation below: [image: Detailed view page]
[image: List view page]

My question is - what tags to use for each of the lists. I have reviewed dozens of threads and over the years the structure of markers has changed and every thread proposes something else. At the moment I really don't know what "markup system" to use on the site.

Is such a sets of tags sufficient enough for:

1. Category and most popular lists:

   ```
   <section itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CollectionPage">
       <article itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">  
           ...
       </article>
       <article itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting"> 
           ...
       </article>
   </section>
   ```
2. Gallery list:

   ```
   <section itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">
       <article itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
           ...
       </article>
       <article itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
           ...
       </article>
   </section>
   ```
3. Article with related news:

   ```
   <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog">
       <article itemprop="blogPost" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
           Article body
       </article>

       <section>
           Related post:
           <article itemprop="blogPost" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
             ...
           </article>
           <article itemprop="blogPost" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
             ...
           </article>
       </section>
   </div>
   ```

P.S. I use Microdata markup, not JSON-LD

Thanks for any help.

Comment: please elaborate your question. Are you asking: for the `@Type`s in the above example, which `properties` to use with each `@Type`? If that is the question, the schema.org documentation is explicit. And you can validate your code on GSDTT to correct errors. Or maybe you are asking something different.

Comment: I mean the main `@Type`s for blocks of links, galleries or related news. Should I use tags e.g. for `Article`, `Blog` etc. or other syntax

Comment: It depends on the `@Type`, meaning that `properties` are `@Type` dependent. I can't "fill in the properties" that are associated with your `@Type`s because I don't know what you wish to express. Alternatively, if you ask a specific question with your example, I can suggest how to correct/improve. But right now your question is a "fishing expedition"